# The function in parent component not getting called?

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I have the following code in this component,

```
<app-steps #appSteps
           [menuSteps]="steps"
           [currentComponent]="outlet?.component"
           (currentStepChange)="currentStep = $event">
  <div appStepBody>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-deploy *ngIf="false" (ruleDeployed)="appSteps.resetStep()"></app-deploy>
  </div>
</app-steps>
```

The app-steps is the parent of app-deploy  in appStepBody. I hide the app-deploy component because it's already displayed in appStepBody and I just want to call a parent function from the child component.

The code for resetStep() is:

```
resetStep(): void {
    console.log('Hello');
}
```

Inside app-deploy:

```
@Output() ruleDeployed = new EventEmitter();
//this method is fired by clicking Deploy button
deploy() {
  this.ruleDeployed.emit();
}
```

However, the console.log("Hello") does not work when I click the Deploy button. I would really appreciate any help. Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: if you are working with router-outlet it's nor means the app-deploy child of app-steps

Comment: What can I do to fix?

Comment: sorry I was thinking that you want to call a child function

Answer (score 0):

`ngIf` doesn't 'hide' your component. These are structural directives, to [quote the docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf):

> A structural directive that conditionally includes a template based on
>   the value of an expression coerced to Boolean.

That means your 'app-deploy' component is never included, you have removed it from the generated page. It can't call any method, because it's not there.

Comment: Honestly I don't really know what you are trying to accomplish. If 'app-deploy' is already part of 'app-steps' then you simply don't wont to include it twice. You would have to change the structure of your components. But that is out of scope of this question, IMHO.